# How to show record in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I got the records like the below

```
employee id        name         org         row        Type
00001               a           asc          1         a
00001               a           asc          1         c
00001               a           asc          1         d
00001               a           asc          1         3
00002               b           asd          2         f
00002               b           asd          2         b
00002               b           asd          2         g
00003               c           aef          3         h
```

I wish to show record in SQL like the below

```
employee id        name         org         row        Type
00001               a           asc          1         a
                                                       c
                                                       d
                                                       3
00002               b           asd          2         f
                                                       b
                                                       g
00003               c           aef          3         h
```

How to do Please help me .Thank in advance

Comment: This is better accomplished in your application's view layer, rather than at the data-access layer. Are you sure you want your raw results to be like this?

Comment: Yes. I wish to show like that.How to do. Can u help me.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN RN > 1  THEN '' ELse employee_id END,
      CASE WHEN RN > 1  THEN '' ELse name END,
      CASE WHEN RN > 1  THEN '' ELse Org END,
      CASE WHEN RN > 1  THEN '' ELse row END,
      Type 
FROM
(
  SELECT *, Row_Number() Over(Partition By employee_id Order by employee_id) AS RN
  FROM Table1
) AS T
```

## [Row_Number](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: Not Ok.u have another idea?

Comment: Why you say it's not Ok?